# Alter the anchor attribute content loaded in iframe source

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a popup iframe content, the source(src) of iframe is a html response generated from a another server. The content includes links, and text. The anchor tag does not have any target attribute, so when we click the link it opens in the same iframe. I need to add target="_parent" to the anchor, using javascript.so that it can be loaded in the parent page.

Is there any way we can alter the anchor attribute using javascript.

Comment: Imagine being able to load Google in an iframe and then modifying the search button so that is loads results from Bing...

Comment: @JamesHill we all dream of the reverse !!!

Comment: @ManseUK, you're telling me! I had to **Google** `search engines other than Google` to find one for my example ;)

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, it is completely impossible to interact with content from another domain (unless it cooperates).

You need to modify the other code.

Comment: Hi , Is there any way we can get a reference to onclick event of the link and instruct js to open the link in theparent window

Comment: Only with cooperation from the other domain.